# How do I get my package listed in pip or easy_install

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

I understand there is already a question about packaging into pip, but this is more generic. On what mechanism does pip identify packages? To which central server should I add the name so that when someone types in

```
pip install <mypackagename>
```

how does pip know, where to look for the package. What should I do to add mine to that name resolution directory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [creating a simple package that can be install via Pip & virtualenv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360458/creating-a-simple-package-that-can-be-install-via-pip-virtualenv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pip pulls from the [Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi).  It is [very easy](http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html) to submit a package, assuming you have a configured setup.py to build the package.

You'll need to register an account on PyPi, have certain metadata defined in setup.py (license, etc), and a setup.cfg if you're using markdown-formatted readme (as on Github).  Then it's just a shell command to register the package :

## Register:

```
python setup.py register -r pypi
```

## Submit:

```
python setup.py sdist upload -r pypi
```

Answer (score 1):

Python's crowdsourced package repository, PyPI, aka the [Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi).

You will want to start with a tutorial on how to package your code for, then submit to, PyPI. [This is one.](http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html) There is a learning curve, but it is most worthwhile.

It helps to look at packages already on PyPI, then follow the links back to their source code repositories to see all of the files and configurations that were used. For example, my [intspan](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/intspan) package is [hosted at bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/jeunice/intspan). As many PyPI packages are hosted at either Bitbucket or Github, so there are many examples available from which to learn.